# Сравнение массивов без подключения библиотеки string.h

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_MAX 2048

char StrCmp(char str1, char str2)
{
    char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
    int a;
    /*if(s1 == s2) return m[0];
    else return m[1];*/
    /*if(s1 == s2)  m[0];
    else  m[1];
    return m;*/
    if(str1 == str2) a = 1;
    else a = 2;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1: "Sample"; break;
        case 2: "Different"; break;
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {
    char str1[STR_MAX];
    char str2[STR_MAX];
    printf("Please enter str1: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Please enter str2: ");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    printf("%s\n", StrCmp(str1, str2));

    return 0;
}
```

Код компилируется, но работает неверно, программа доходит до вывода результата на экран и вылетает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Во-первых, вы сравниваете указатели на строки: `if(str1 == str2)`, а надо сравнивать их содержимое, посимвольно. Во-вторых, `StrCmp` возвращает `char`, а надо `const char*`.

Comment: А как сравнивать посимвольно?

Comment: циклом идти по строке и каждый элемент сравнивать

Comment: В цикле сравнивать `str1[i] == str2[i]`. Может вам для начала man strcmp прочесть?

Comment: То есть, запросить у пользователя сколько символов он собирается ввести и далее каждый сравнивать?

Comment: Сравнение строк `const char* str1` и `const char* str2`: `size_t offset = 0; while(str1[offset] == str2[offset] && str1[offset] != '\0') ++offset; bool len = str2[offset] == str1[offset];`. Результат сравнения окажется в `areEqual` (`true` для равных строк и `false` для неравных).

Comment: Зачем? Прочтите все же man и задумайтесь. Кстати, а зачем вам все это?

Comment: *"Код компилируется"* -- а вы хоть одно предупреждение компилятора при этом прочитали, попробовали понять о чём там речь? Что они есть даже не сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

> Код компилируется

Давайте для начала вместе почитаем что пишет компилятор.

```
../main.c: In function ‘StrCmp’:
../main.c:8:15: warning: character constant too long for its type
     char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
               ^
```

Объявлен массив символов, который инициализируется непонятно чем. Если вы действительно хотели объявить такой массив, то было бы правильно:

```
 char m[]={'S','D'};
```

Или:

```
 char m[]={"Sample"};
```

Но, видимо, имелось в виду всё-таки объявить массив строк (указателей на строки):

```
 char *m[]={"Sample","Different"};
```

Кстати, что значит "Sample" в данном контексте?

---

```
../main.c:8:15: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
../main.c:8:24: warning: character constant too long for its type
     char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
                        ^
../main.c:8:24: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Следствия предыдущей ошибки.

---

```
../main.c:19:17: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
         case 1: "Sample"; break;
                 ^
../main.c:20:17: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
         case 2: "Different"; break;
                 ^
```

Бессмысленный код, который ничего не делает.

---

```
../main.c:8:10: warning: unused variable ‘m’ [-Wunused-variable]
     char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
          ^
```

Всё ещё следствия первой ошибки.

---

```
../main.c: In function ‘main’:
../main.c:32:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘StrCmp’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     printf("%s\n", StrCmp(str1, str2));
                           ^
../main.c:6:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 char StrCmp(char str1, char str2)
      ^
../main.c:32:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘StrCmp’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     printf("%s\n", StrCmp(str1, str2));
                                 ^
../main.c:6:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 char StrCmp(char str1, char str2)
      ^
```

Аргументы функции `StrCmp` объявлены как символы (`char`), а передаёте ей указатели на `char`.

---

```
../main.c:32:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s\n", StrCmp(str1, str2));
```

Функция `StrCmp` возвращает `char` (при приведении типов будет `int`), а в спецификации формата указано выводить как строку (`%s`)

Выводы? Читайте учебник по C...

Answer (score 1):

В этой функции

```
char StrCmp(char str1, char str2)
{
    char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
    int a;
    /*if(s1 == s2) return m[0];
    else return m[1];*/
    /*if(s1 == s2)  m[0];
    else  m[1];
    return m;*/
    if(str1 == str2) a = 1;
    else a = 2;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1: "Sample"; break;
        case 2: "Different"; break;
    }
    return a;
}
```

параметры имеют тип `char` вместо указателей `char *`. Поэтому уже изначально функция неверна.

В этом объявлении

```
    char m[]={'Sample','Different'};
```

используются символьные константы, которые имеют зависящее от реализации компилятора представление.

Данное switch предложение

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1: "Sample"; break;
    case 2: "Different"; break;
}
```

не имеет смысла, так как оно, фактически, ничего не делает.

Функция возвращает объект типа `char`, который вы пытаетесь вывести как строку

```
printf("%s\n", StrCmp(str1, str2));
```

Внутри функции вам следует сравнивать каждую пару соответствующих символов строк.

Также функция `scanf` со спецификатором формата, как он задан у вас, является небезопасной и может привести к выходу за границу символьного массива.

То, что вы хотите получить, похоже, должно выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * StrCmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    const char * m[] = { "different", "same", };

    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1; ++s2;
    }

    return m[*s1 == *s2];
}   

#define STR_MAX 2048

int main( void ) 
{
    char s1[STR_MAX];
    char s2[STR_MAX];

    printf( "Please enter str1: " );
    fgets( s1, sizeof( s1 ), stdin );

    printf( "Please enter str2: " );
    fgets( s2, sizeof( s2 ), stdin );

    printf("The strings are %s\n", StrCmp( s1, s2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Например, если ввести две строки `Hello`, то вывод программы будет выглядеть как

```
Please enter str1: Hello
Please enter str2: Hello
The strings are same
```

Если же одна введенная строка будет иметь значение `Hello`, а другая `hello`, то вывод программы будет выглядеть как

```
Please enter str1: Hello
Please enter str2: hello
The strings are different
```

Правда, в общем случае лучше, когда функция возвращает целочисленный результат сравнения вместо указателя на строковый литерал. То есть более универсальная функция может выглядеть как

```
int StrCmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1; ++s2;
    }

    return *s1 == *s2;
}
```

Эта функция возвращает 1, если строки равны, и ноль - в противном случае.

Стандартная функция `strcmp` не только сообщает равны ли строки, но и предоставляет информацию о том, какая строка больше или меньше в случае, если строки не равны.

Обратите внимание на то, что функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена в C следующим образом

```
int main( void )
```